# ¿Como puedo replicar esto con python?

Tags: python

Estaba intentado replicar este diccionario para mandar un request a una web:

```
{
  "optInAdsFlags": 11,
  "timezone": -300,
  "userActiveTimeChunkList": [
    {
      "end": 1615491603,
      "start": 1615491600
    },
    {
      "end": 1615491644,
      "start": 1615491614
    },
    {
      "end": 1615491652,
      "start": 1615491648
    }
  ]
}
```

Con este codigo:

```
lista = []
for x in range(10):
    dic = {'end': int(timestamp() * 1000), 'start': int(timestamp() * 1000)}
    lista.append(dic)

data = json.dumps({
       "optInAdsFlags": 11,
       "timezone": -300,
       "userActiveTimeChunkList": lista
})
```

La cosa es que me da mal los numeros, o sea los repite todos y queda así

```
{
  "optInAdsFlags": 11,
  "timezone": -300,
  "userActiveTimeChunkList": [
    {
      "end": 1615491652,
      "start": 1615491648
    },
    {
      "end": 1615491652,
      "start": 1615491648
    },
    {
      "end": 1615491652,
      "start": 1615491648
    }
  ]
}
```

¿Como puedo usar bien lo de timestamp? o que al menos no se repitan, de ante mano gracias por la ayuda. Tambien tenia otra duda de si era bueno usar de esa forma el meter datos al diccionario y luego a la lista

Comment: dic no apunta siempre a lo mismo?

Comment: Claro, pero intenta agregar siempre nuevos timestamps. Cambie de tiempo en cada uno con un sleep y funciono, pero no cambie el start, sigue siendo el mismo end y start

Comment: ¿Que buscas con start y end? ¿que valor deberían tener?

Comment: Es la actividad que mantiene una cuenta, tengo entendido que seria el minuto donde comienza y termina, es como ir sumando experiencia, quiero replicar eso mismo, pero los valores o me dan igual en ambos o todos en cada dic que ponga en la lista son iguales

Comment: @PatricioMoracho yo veo mal, o dic es uno solo por mas que lo agregues 20 a la lista... y si le cambias los valores no es siempre el mismo? no se deberia crear un nuevo objeto en cada iteracion?

Comment: Es que comienza solamente con     {
      "end": 1615491652,
      "start": 1615491648 } mientras pasa el tiempo se van agregando mas, pero con nuevos valores, tal cual como dices de agregar un nuevo objeto en la iteracion

Comment: Puede ser porque el loop corre tan rápido que el timestamp no cambia. Probá multiplicando el timestamp por x y vas a tener diferentes valores.

Comment: @gbianchi,  el tema es que los valores los completa con un `timestamp() ` que dependerá, imagino, de la resolución del timmer interno y de cuan rápido se vaya completando el ciclo

Comment: el new del objeto es implicito en python?? en cualquier lenguaje decente :p deberias aclararlo.. por eso te preguntaba... mas alla que tienen razon con lo de los tiempos...

Comment: Igualmente ahora que lo miro mejor, `timestamp()` que es?  por que si es del modulo `datetime` la forma en que lo llamas no me cierra. Si es una función tuya, ¿podrías agregar el código de la misma?

Comment: @gbianchi Dentro del scope del ciclo si, es un nuevo objeto con cada iteración, y además por tratarse de un objeto mutable.

Comment: gratzie Pato!!!

Comment: @PatricioMoracho timestamps es para marcar cuando comenzo un evento en fracciones de segundos, y si, se me olvido agregar el modulo que usaba, perdona, es `from time import time as timestamp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas:

1. Las diferencias entre las lecturas de `timestamp()` son muy pequeñas
2. Esta convirtiendo estas lecturas a un `int` perdiendo precisión

Veamos un ejemplo:

```
from time import time as timestamp

start, end = (timestamp(), timestamp())

print(start, end)
print(start == end)

1615500122.916606 1615500122.9166064
False
```

---

La diferencia en las lecturas de los `timestamp()` dependen básicamente de la resolución del reloj interno de Python que a su vez depende de (a) la versión de Python (b) el Sistema Operativo. Podemos ver que la diferencia entre dos lecturas prácticamente simultaneas es muy pequeña, y en la parte decimal, pero aún así suficiente para que ambas lecturas sean distintas.

Ahora cuando haces esto:

```
print(int(start) == int(end))
True
```

---

Al quitar la parte decimal, pierdes la precisión de las lecturas (quedan con una precisión de 1 segundo) y por consiguiente los valores serán idénticos.

Si necesitas hacer una simulación, entonces lo que puedes hacer es generar un "delay" artificial aleatorio, de un rango predefinido. Por ejemplo, algo así:

```
from time import time as timestamp
from random import randint
from time import sleep
lista = []
for x in range(10):

    start = timestamp()
    sleep(randint(1,3)) # delay random de 1 a 3 segundos
    end = timestamp()

    dic = {'end': int(end), 'start': int(start)}
    lista.append(dic)
```

---

Ahora bien, ¿es necesario generar delay artificiales? no, no lo es, bien puedes partir de un `timestamp()` y generar los valores siguientes a partir de esta "semilla", generando intervalo aleatorios:

```
lista = []
start = int(timestamp())
for x in range(10):
  end = start + randint(1,3)
  dic = {'end': int(end), 'start': int(start)}
  lista.append(dic)
  start = start + end

print(lista)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ayudo bastante tu explicación @PatricioMoracho !!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo pienso es que cuando conviertes a entero, te estas comiendo los microsegundos, y para el script que tarda muy poco en ejecutarse, los tiempos vendrian siendo los mismos, solo diferenciandose en esos microsegundos.

Este es el codigo que hice:

```
import datetime
import time
import json
lista = []
for x in range(10):
    start = datetime.datetime.now() #Se obtiene la fecha en la que se ejecuta la iteracion
    end = start + datetime.timedelta(seconds = 100) #Se añade 100 segundos
    dic = {'end': int(end.timestamp() * 1000), 'start': int(start.timestamp() * 1000)}
lista.append(dic)
#Esperamos 1 segundo
time.sleep(1)

data = json.dumps({
   "optInAdsFlags": 11,
   "timezone": -300,
   "userActiveTimeChunkList": lista
},indent = 4) #indent = 4 para que al hacer un print se muestre con una identaciond e 4 espacios
print(data)
```

En cada iteracion obtengo la fecha para que siempre este cambiando y se obtenga resultados distintos.

y el resultado seria este

```
{
"optInAdsFlags": 11,
"timezone": -300,
"userActiveTimeChunkList": [  
    {
        "end": 1615499621590, 
        "start": 1615499521590
    },
    {
        "end": 1615499622590, 
        "start": 1615499522590
    },
    {
        "end": 1615499623590, 
        "start": 1615499523590
    },
    {
        "end": 1615499624590,
        "start": 1615499524590
    },
    {
        "end": 1615499625591,
        "start": 1615499525591
    },
    {
        "end": 1615499626591,
        "start": 1615499526591
    },
    {
        "end": 1615499627592,
        "start": 1615499527592
    },
    {
        "end": 1615499628592,
        "start": 1615499528592
    },
    {
        "end": 1615499629593,
        "start": 1615499529593
    },
    {
        "end": 1615499630593,
        "start": 1615499530593
    }
  ]
}
```

Algo que se puede notar es que a nivel de los milisegundos son muy similares, es por esto que si no se añade el sleep, al convertirlo a entero los numeros vendrian a ser iguales para el numero limitado de muestras que se tiene. Por eso tambien he añadido 100 segundos a la variable "end" para que el resultado sea diferente.

Comment: ¿Tengo que crear un sleep para que el tiempo se diferencie mas notablemente?

Comment: si podrias añadirle un sleep o usar un timedelta (datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)) para añadirle al start algo asi como  end = start + timedelta

Comment: Danke vielmals !! @Krengifo

Comment: "Pensar que" no es una respuesta. Una buena respuesta identifica el problema (no lo has hecho) y da una solución con código probado, que tampoco has hecho.

Comment: tiene razon. voy a postear el codigo que hice